# Excel formula to return unique relationships

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking to return the unique relationships for the following data set which is stored in an array A2#:

Sample Data:

| DATA |
| --- |
| 0123|ABC|EUR|ABC|3210 |
| 3210|ABC|EUR|ABC|0123 |
| 0123|ABC|USD|ABC|3210 |
| 3210|ABC|USD|ABC|0123 |
| 1111|ABC|EUR|ABC|9999 |
| 9999|ABC|EUR|ABC|1111 |
| 2222|ABC|GBP|ABC|0001 |
| 3333|ABC|GBP|ABC|9999 |
| 0123|ABC|AUD|ABC|9999 |
| 9999|ABC|AUD|ABC|0123 |

I have tried the following which returns one side of all unique two-way relationships and one-way relationships where the the left number is smaller than the right but ingnores one way relationships where the left number is larger than the right:

```
=FILTER(A2#,LEFT(A2#,4)<RIGHT(A2#,4))
```

Output of attempt:

| OUTPUT |
| --- |
| 0123|ABC|EUR|ABC|3210 |
| 0123|ABC|USD|ABC|3210 |
| 1111|ABC|EUR|ABC|9999 |
| 3333|ABC|GBP|ABC|9999 |
| 0123|ABC|AUD|ABC|9999 |

Expected output would be an array of:

| OUTPUT |
| --- |
| 0123|ABC|EUR|ABC|3210 |
| 0123|ABC|USD|ABC|3210 |
| 1111|ABC|EUR|ABC|9999 |
| 3333|ABC|GBP|ABC|9999 |
| 0123|ABC|AUD|ABC|9999 |
| **2222**|**ABC**|**GBP**|**ABC**|**0001** |

Where I am strugling with the last record where the condition is false for this one way relationship.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you mean is, if a value has an equivalent where the right 4 characters and left 4 characters are swapped, only list the (unique?) values where the left value is smaller.

If it doesn't have an equivalent like that, it should list these (or the unique values of these).

The following formula returns that:

```
=LET(a,A2#,
     UNIQUE(FILTER(a,
                     (LEFT(a,4)<RIGHT(a,4))
                     +
                     (ISNA(XMATCH(RIGHT(a,4)&MID(a,5,LEN(a)-8)&LEFT(a,4),a))))))
```

If you don't need the uniques, just drop the `UNIQUES()`